# SQLAlchemy: how to select if in one list or another list?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a class which looks something like this:

```
class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = "a";
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    stuff = relationship('Stuff', secondary=stuff_a)
    more_stuff = relationship('Stuff', secondary=more_stuff_a)
```

Basically two lists, stuff and more_stuff containing lists of Stuff.

I want to do a query which selects all A which have Stuff with id=X in either stuff list or in more_stuff list.

This is how I would do it for one list:

```
session.query(A).join(Stuff).filter(Stuff.id==X)
```

But that won't pick up Stuff from more_stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that if you have two relationships from `A` to `Stuff`, even when you join for one, you need to explicitly specify which one, or `sqlalchemy` will rightfully complain. You can do this as follows:

```
q = (
    session
    .query(A)
    .join(Stuff, A.stuff)  # @note: here you specify the relationship
    .filter(Stuff.id == X)
)
```

As to filter for both lists, you need to use an `or_` operator in a filter. In order to be able to reference to both relationships, the easiest is to create aliases (give different names) to each of them. Then the code looks like below:

```
S1 = aliased(Stuff)
S2 = aliased(Stuff)
q = (
    session
    .query(A)
    .join(S1, A.stuff)  # S1 will refer to `A.stuff`
    .join(S2, A.more_stuff)  # S2 will refer to `A.more_stuff`
    .filter(or_(S1.id == X, S2.id == X))
)
```

Alternatively, a *cleaner* code can be achieved with `relationship.any()`:

```
q = (
    session
    .query(A)
    .filter(or_(
        A.stuff.any(Stuff.id == X),  # here Stuff will refer to `A.stuff`
        A.more_stuff.any(Stuff.id == X),  # here Stuff will refer to `A.more_stuff`
    ))
)
```

but you will need to compare performance difference between two versions as the latter is implemented using `EXISTS` with sub-selects.

Comment: Thanks. I went with the aliased version.